# Android Studio error: "manifest merger failed attribute metadata#android.support.version""

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-manifest

I am a newbie and I cant run my tiny project because of some error that I can not solve. Check it out please:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(25.3.0) from [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0] AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-31
>       is also present at [com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.3.1] AndroidManifest.xml:24:9-31 value=(25.3.1).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:25:5-27:34 to override.

Answer (score 0):

Your support libraries must be all in the same version. What the message is saying to you is that you have `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0` and `com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.3.1`. So, match all support libraries to the same version.